# Beanshell will not allow me to add jars to the "default" JRE classloader?

Tags: java, classloader, beanshell, dynamic-class-loaders, groovyclassloader

I have a question about [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshmanual.html) that I can't find an answer to anywhere.  I am only able to run Beanshell scripts in 1 of 2 ways:

1. Where Classpath is defined before invoking Beanshell and Beanshell uses 
   the JRE default classloader.
2. Where no classpath is defined at all before starting Beanshell and then I use 
   `addClassPath()` and `importCommands()` to dynamically build the classpath
    within Beanshell's classloader.  This method does not seem to inherit a jars 
    that were part of the default JRE classloader.

After much experimentation, I have learned that I am unable to start a script with a pre-defined Classpath and then be able to add to the classpath by using `addClassPath()`.   I don't know if this is as-designed **or if I am doing something wrong**?

It is very easy to see for yourself what my problem is.  For example, here is the script:

```
::Test.bat (where bsh.jar exists in JRE/lib/ext directory)
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME=C:\JDK1.6.0_27
:: first invoke:  this first command works
%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\java.exe bsh.Interpreter Test.bsh
:: second invoke: this command fails
%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\java.exe -cp ant.jar bsh.Interpreter Test.bsh
```

The second invoke causes this error:

```
Evaluation Error: Sourced file: Test.bsh : Command not 
found: helloWorld() : at Line: 5 : in file: Test.bsh : helloWorld ( )
```

Test.bat launches this Beanshell script:

```
// Test.bsh
System.out.println("Trying to load commands at: " + "bin" );
addClassPath("bin");  
importCommands("bin");
helloWorld();
```

And, this is my helloWorld.bsh script:

```
// File: helloWorld.bsh
helloWorld() { 
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Test.bsh` has a slight error: `importCommands` looks for a directory called "bin" in the class path and loads all .bsh files from there, so what you should add to `addClassPath` is the current directory:

```
// Test.bsh
System.out.println("Trying to load commands at: " + "bin" );
addClassPath(".");  // current directory
importCommands("bin");
helloWorld();
```

The code you had works in the first case because the current directory is in the default system class path.  The problem is that the `-cp` switch overrides the default class path, so `importCommands` no longer has any way to find the `bin` directory.

Alternatively you can add `.` to the classpath on the JVM level:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\java.exe -cp .;ant.jar bsh.Interpreter Test.bsh
```

Comment: Yep, that worked.  I can't believe I overlooked that.  Thank you very very much!