# Custom classloader for standalone Windows app without configuring PATH

Tags: java, windows, classloader

My application uses an educational UI framework ([Arena](http://code.google.com/p/uqbar-arena/)) that requires a custom classloader. Normally, I would create a script that runs `java -Djava.system.class.loader=...` but on Windows this will fail unless `java` is in the user's PATH.

What is the best way to make my application (with its custom classloader) standalone and runnable without needing to configure PATH?

Comment: How do you run your application now, when scripts don’t work?

Comment: I'm developing it using Eclipse with VM arguments for the classloader in my runnable's launch options.

Comment: So you have no stand-alone launch solution anyway, regardless of the class loader replacement, right? You might look for launcher solution like in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018217/can-i-set-java-max-heap-size-for-running-from-a-jar-file

Comment: Correct, as of right now I have no launch solution. launch4j seems to be what I'm looking for, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beanshell will not allow me to add jars to the "default" JRE classloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535802/beanshell-will-not-allow-me-to-add-jars-to-the-default-jre-classloader)